# AWS cross account Loki promtail setup in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio, grafana-loki, promtail

Here is my setup.

I have 2 AWS accounts.

1. Applications account
2. Monitoring account

Application account has EKS + Istio + Application related microservices + promtail agents.

Monitoring account has centralized logging system within EKS + Istio + (Grafana & Prometheus & loki pods running)

From Applications account, I want to push logs to Loki on Monitoring a/c. I tried exposing Loki service outside monitoring a/c but I am facing issues to set loki url as https://<DNS_URL>/loki. This change I tried by using suggestions at [here](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/144#issuecomment-663631289) and [here](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/1668#issuecomment-584406225), but that is not working for me. I have installed the loki-stack from [this url](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack)

The question is how can I access loki URL from applications account so that it can be configured in promtail in applications a/c?
Please note both accounts are using pods within EKS and not standalone loki or promtail.

Thanks and regards.

```
apiVersion: v1                                
kind: Service                                 
metadata:                                     
  annotations:                                
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki           
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: monitoring
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-25T14:59:20Z"   
  labels:                                     
    app: loki                                 
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm        
    chart: loki-2.5.0                         
    heritage: Helm                            
    release: loki                             
  name: loki                                  
  namespace: monitoring                       
  resourceVersion: "18279654"                 
  uid: 7eba14cb-41c9-445d-bedb-4b88647f1ebc   
spec:                                         
  clusterIP: 172.20.217.122                   
  clusterIPs:                                 
  - 172.20.217.122                            
  ports:                                      
  - name: metrics                             
    port: 80                                  
    protocol: TCP                             
    targetPort: 3100                          
  selector:                                   
    app: loki                                 
    release: loki                             
  sessionAffinity: None                       
  type: ClusterIP                             
status:                                       
  loadBalancer: {}                            
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  generation: 14
  name: grafana-vs
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "18256422"
  uid: e8969da7-062c-49d6-9152-af8362c08016
spec:
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /grafana/
    name: grafana-ui
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: prometheus-operator-grafana.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /loki
    name: loki-ui
    rewrite:
      uri: /loki
    route:
    - destination:
        host: loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.istio.io/v1alpha3","kind":"Gateway","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-gateway","namespace":"monitoring"},"spec":{"selector":{"istio":"ingressgateway"},"servers":[{"hosts":["*"],"port":{"name":"http","number":80,"protocol":"HTTP"}}]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-18T12:28:05Z"
  generation: 1
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: monitoring
  resourceVersion: "16618724"
  uid: 9b254a22-958c-4cc4-b426-4e7447c03b87
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP

---
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme":"internal","alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type":"ip","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"alb"},"name":"ingress-alb","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"istio-ingressgateway","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}]}}
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    finalizers:
    - ingress.k8s.aws/resources
    generation: 1
    name: ingress-alb
    namespace: istio-system
    resourceVersion: "4447931"
    uid: 74b31fba-0f03-41c6-a63f-6a10dee8780c
  spec:
    rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: istio-ingressgateway
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /*
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - hostname: internal-k8s-istiosys-ingressa-25a256ef4d-1368971909.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

The ingress is associated with AWS ALB.

I want to access Loki from ALB URL like http(s)://my-alb-url/loki
I hope I have provided the required details now.
Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`...how can I access loki URL from applications account so that it can be configured in promtail in applications a/c?`

You didn't describe what issue when you use external LB above which should work, anyway, since this method will go thru Internet, the security risk is higher with egress cost consider the volume of logging. You can use [Privatelink](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-privatelink.pdf) in this case, see page 16 Shared Services. Your promtail will use the ENI DNS name as the loki target.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gohm'c. I was trying to expose the service using LB but the problem is if I make change as per the suggested links which I mentioned in my post, Loki is not getting exposed and I can not access it from anywhere else except from Grafana dashboard. So wondering how to expose Loki outside EKS cluster using LB?

Comment: The GitHub issue links you posted are mainly for loki fronted by reverse proxy that expected to do path rewrite. But your question read like you want pods running in diff. EKS/account to be able to log to a loki in a specific EKS/account, right? If this is true, you can use NLB if not PrivateLink (recommended).

Comment: Yes gohm'c. I am trying to expose the Loki service but when I make changes, the loki service is not accessible through NLB and that is where I  am stuck. If you know any reference where I can refer the configuration changes then please let me know. I tried but still waiting to get success.

Comment: Post the service spec that you used to `expose the Loki service ` in the question.

Comment: Hi gohm's, please see the updates in the question

Comment: Base on the service status, there's no ALB being created for your loki service.

Comment: Hi gohm'c, No the ALB is already created and available. I am able to access Grafana service on the same ALB but not loki, I am wondering why?

Comment: You didn't post the service status for Grafana. But your loki is `status: loadBalancer: {}`